# LInux replace sleep calls with process status check

Tags: linux, command-line

Linux bash commend:

I have .sh scripts as follows which has couple of sleep calls, is there a way i can replace  sleep calls b/c sleep time may not be accurate, i want to check process running time and continue once previous process finish.

```
./deploy.sh
sleep 60
./stop-tomcat.sh
sleep 60
./start-tomcat.sh stop
```

Help appreciated.

Comment: re-write `deploy.sh` etc so that they don't return until they are finished.  Any other solution is a fragile hack.

Comment: ya this is one option i have

Comment: why do you think that your scripts will not have finished before executing the `sleep` commands in your list? Based on the code you've posted, each line should execute, only after the previous line has completed. You don't have a back-ground task in a deploy script do you? If so, read about the `bash|ksh|zsh`s `wait` command. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-- Find the PID

```
$ pgrep gcalctool
15435
```

wait un-child process to be wait

```
while [ -e /proc/15435 ]; do sleep 0.1; done
```